# The text position in TextForm is different between iText5 and iText7

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm trying to update from iText5 to iText7. In that, I'm aware that the text top position in TextField is difference. See the link image, It is hard to see the difference but the text position is not same; the text position in the pdf generated by iText 7 is slightly upper.
[image: Comparing Text poistion PDF Image]

The pdf generation code by iText5

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("itext5.pdf"));
writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
writer.setTagged();
doc.open();
doc.addTitle("itext5 sample");
TextField tf = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(100, 100, 261, 131), "text");
tf.setTextColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
tf.setFontSize(0);
tf.setText("TEST");
writer.addAnnotation(tf.getTextField());
doc.close();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("itext5.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("itext5_flatten.pdf"));
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
```

The pdf generation code by iText7

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("itext7_flatten.pdf"));

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(doc, true);
PdfTextFormField nameField = PdfTextFormField.createText(doc, new Rectangle(100, 100, 161, 31), "text", "TEST");
nameField.setFontSize(0);
form.addField(nameField);
form.flattenFields();

doc.close();
```

I searched iText API as much as possible, but any API change text position in TextField seemed to be not provided. Could I adjust text poistion in TextField, in iText7 ?

The source codes and PDf files I used is [here](https://github.com/Nobuyuki-Inaba/itext5and7).

Comment: The process of creating PDF form field appearances is not specified in complete detail, so with different libraries there always is a chance of slightly differing looks.

Comment: Hi mkl, 
Thanks for your quick reply.

As you said, I got it there is a chance of slight dirrences with diffrent libraries.
Do you have any idea which parts I have to specify  detail appearances, it would be great if you have.

Comment: I've not dived into the details of iText 7 appearance generation yet, so I unfortunately don't know how. One thing complicating this: iText 7 slightly differently determines some font properties from the font data, so that might also make a difference here.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried some method (setFont, setFontSize, setJustification, etc) but I couldn't adjust the position.Therefore, I moved the Textfield position itself as workaround, so that the position after flattened to be get same position.